# Animation - pygame.time.wait()

Tags: python, animation, pygame, wait

My code isn't working and I don't understand it why, I'm working with module PYGAME and I want do a animation (three images) when I push the key "**s**". My code is this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from time import *

pygame.init()
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hi!")
imgA = pygame.image.load("IMG/fan_azul.png")
imgB = pygame.image.load("IMG/fan_naranja.png")
imgC = pygame.image.load("IMG/fan_rojo.png")
listaImg = [imgA,imgB,imgC]
POS,aux,e = 0,1,0
picture = listaImg[POS]
posX,posY,fondo = 200,100,(50,50,50)

while True:
    ventana.fill(fondo)
    #ventana.blit(picture,(posX,posY))
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif evento.type == KEYDOWN:
                if evento.key == K_s:
                    for e in range(0,3):
                        POS = e
                        picture = listaImg[POS]
                        ventana.blit(picture,(posX,posY))
                        print "TIEMPO MEDIDO: "+str(POS)
                        pygame.time.wait(1000)
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Is the indentation on `pygame.display.update()` correct?  If so, it will never be executed.  It looks like it should be indented at the same level as `pygame.time.wait(1000)`

Comment: You're the best!! Thanks very much!!! All ok! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is important to avoid inner loops that are going to hang up processing events and other drawing to the frame.  Remember you are usually trying to get 30 to 60 frames per second, and your K_s handler is taking 3 seconds by itself.  Keep the handle events, update state, and draw screen parts all separate. To do an animation, I usually do something like this.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import time

pygame.init()
ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hi!")
FONDO = (50,50,50)

class AnimatedSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, position, filenames):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = [pygame.image.load(filename) for filename in filenames]
        self.delay = 0
        self.start = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(position, (0, 0))
        self._set_image(0)
    def _set_image(self, image_num):
        self.image_num = image_num
        self.image = self.images[self.image_num]
        self.rect.size = self.image.get_rect().size
    def show(self, group, delay=1.0):
        group.add(self)
        self.delay = delay
        self._set_image(0)
        self.start = time.time()
    def update(self):
        if self.alive() and time.time() - self.start > self.delay:
            if self.image_num + 1 < len(self.images):
                self._set_image(self.image_num + 1)
            else:
                self.kill()


fan = AnimatedSprite((200, 10), ["IMG/fan_azul.png",
                                 "IMG/fan_naranja.png",
                                 "IMG/fan_rojo.png"])
animation = pygame.sprite.Group()

while True:
    # Handle Events
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif evento.type == KEYDOWN:
                if evento.key == K_s:
                    fan.show(animation)

    # Update State
    animation.update()

    # Draw
    ventana.fill(FONDO)
    animation.draw(ventana)
    pygame.display.update()
```